# JSC_NAME_REFERENCE_IN_EXTERNS accessing name in externs has no effect. Perhaps you forgot to add a var keyword?

Tags: closures, google-closure-compiler

How to solve following error which is in externs.js

[JSC_NAME_REFERENCE_IN_EXTERNS] accessing name ‘FuncHello’ in externs has no effect. Perhaps you forgot to add a var keyword?

Utility function

```
util.js

function FuncHello(param1, param2) {
       ...
}
```

File to use the FuncHello(...)

```
use_the_util_func.js

var abc = FuncHello(1, 2);
```

File to externalize the function ‘FuncHello’.

```
externs.js

/**
 * @fileoverview Extern declarations
 *
 * @externs
 */

/**
 * Utility function externs.
 *
 * @param {number} param1
 * @param {number} param2
 */
 var FuncHello = function (param1, param2) {};  // Error here !!!
```

BUILD file.

```
js_library(
    name = "externs",
    srcs = ["externs.js"],
    deps = [
    ],
)

js_library(
    name = "util",
    srcs = [
        "util.js",
    ],
    deps = [
        "//javascript/closure:base",
        "//javascript/closure/dom",
        "//javascript/closure/dom:safe",
        ":externs",
    ],
)
```